# Why is this relation true? $ \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2 = \binom{2n+1}{3}$

Tags: summation, combinations

I was messing around in wolfram and I found this formula. Why is this true?
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2 = \binom{2n+1}{3}=1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+\ldots+(2n-1)^2 $$

It is basically saying how many ways can you take $3$ elements out of a set with an odd number of elements ($2n+1$).

Comment: You can prove it using induction. A general way to find these identities is to note that for a polynomial $P\in\mathbb R[x]$ of degree $r$, we have that $\sum_{k=1}^n P(k)$ is a polynomial function of degree $r+1$ in $n$. So you can also compute the first $r+2$ values of the sum by hand and then compute the unique interpolating polynomial .

Comment: In other words, you only need to check your identity for $n=1,2,3,4$ to conclude with the argument outlined above that it is true for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Integers which are not even are called odd.  The final term on the right-hand side should be $(2n - 1)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a combinatorial proof.

How many ways are there to choose 3 items from $M$ items?

We can arrange the $M$ items into $\lceil M/2 \rceil$ piles of two items each: pile 1, pile 2, $\ldots$. The last pile might have only one item if $M$ is odd.

Let us count the number of ways that pick zero items from the first $(k-1)$ piles, and that pick more than zero items from the $k$'th pile. From the $k$'th pile, we can either pick both items, or we can pick one of two. The number of ways that involve picking both items is $(M-2k)$. And the number of ways that involve picking one of two is $2 {M-2k \choose 2}$. Adding these two expressions yields $(M-2k)^2$.

Adding this up over all possible choices of $k$ yields the expression:

$$(M-2)^2 + (M-4)^2 + \cdots$$

Plugging in $M=2n+1$ yields the given identity.

Answer (score 0):

Let $${2n-1 \choose 3}=A,$$
then
$${2n+1\choose 3}=A+{2n-1 \choose 2}\cdot {2 \choose 1}+{2n-1\choose 1}\cdot{2\choose 2}=\\A+(2n-2)(2n-1)+(2n-1)=A+(2n-1)^2$$